# Can't find AppDelegate.m

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, appdelegate

I'm having a weird issue with my xcode project.

I renamed my AppDelegate.m file to .mm, thinking I should implement c++ methods there, and changed my mind, moved the C++ calls to the view controller, and renamed AppDelegate to .m
But now when I try to build (it built just fine when it was named .mm and before changing the names at all) it says that it can't find AppDelegate.m and won't launch.

I've verified that the AppDelegate.m is in the Compile Sources in the settings..
If you need any more details, please let me know, I doubt if there's a code I can post to help you guys..

A few things that I already tried:

- Removing the reference to the file and adding it again
- Cleaning the project and rebuilding
- Removing from the Compile Sources and re-adding it
- Restarting xcode and the computer

All failed

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete derived data. That usually does the trick with linking problems .

Comment: Thanks for you answer, tried, but it didn't work, same thing after deleting

Comment: well that sucks. When i run into stupid problems like these i create a new project and copy everything into the new project ( all the files i've made) and for the problem file i copy all it's content ( copy-paste) . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, open the project in XCode, then navigate to Build Phases, in Compile Sources remove the AppDelegate.m file and add AppDelegate.mm instead.